# Vim - confusing search behavior for repeated character

Tags: regex, vim

Say I have a line with a repeating character and my cursor is at the start of the line, e.g.

```
[=]===================
```

If I run `/=`, the `=` sign just after the cursor is highlighted, as expected.

```
=[=]==================
```

However, if I then search for `/==`, I would expect

```
=[==]=================
```

but instead I get

```
==[==]================
```

Likewise, for `/===` I would expect

```
=[===]================
```

but instead I get

```
===[===]==============
```

Can someone explain this behavior?  Is this a bug or by design?

**EDIT**

I see even stranger behavior when searching backwards.  Say my cursor is just below that line:

`?=`: (expected)

```
===================[=]
```

`?==`: (expected)

```
==================[==]
```

`?===`: (expected)

```
=================[===]
```

`?====`: (unexpected)

```
===============[====]==
```

`?=====`: (unexpected)

```
============[=====]===
```

`?======`: (expected)

```
==============[======]
```

`?=======`: (unexpected)

```
============[=======]=
```

`?========`: (unexpected)

```
======[========]======
```

I'm really curious to hear an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: It's by design.  Looking for the next occurrence of the pattern starts where the previous occurrence ended.  This is done for efficiency reasons.

Comment: is that behavior different from "next occurrence starts at next occurrence after the cursor" in any cases other than this one?  If you can elaborate a bit more on how vim's behavior works in an answer I'll accept.

Comment: That's the way it's done in all languages I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strange indeed. Vim seems to look for matches from the beginning of the line and then compares the match with your cursor position.

```
12[3]212321
```

Now you want to go to the 5th position and you look for `12321`.
The first match on the line is from position 1. That will match

```
[12321]2321
```

Since the `1`on the fifth position is already used for the first match, `vim` will not see the match

```
1232[12321]
```

In your case, with `/===` from

```
[=]===================
```

the first match on the line is skipped, and the cursor will jump to the second match.

```
===[===]==============
```

Edit:
Searching backwards will also count the matches from the beginning of the line.
When you have a 20 character string

```
====================
```

and looking back for `?===` will start making matches from the beginning of the line:

```
=== === === === === === ==
```

and will match

```
=== === === === ===[===]==
```

Matching will still be done reading from left to right, so you will not find an apple here:

```
reversed elppa
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  Any accounting for the irregular behavior in backwards search, when my cursor is not on the line?  I know this was an edit to the original question but it seems even more confounding.

Comment: (not sure if that's how Vim behaves out of the box or if it's the result of some plugin or something in my vimrc, though I don't think I have any plugins that really should mess with search).

Comment: Your backward searches seem to have typo's. The first examples are with 20 `=` on one line, later 21. The last search. for 6 characters `======` seem to give you an eight character match `[========]`.

Comment: Thanks I'll go back and fix the typos.

Comment: Also fwiw I'm using a 20 chars for brevity in typing and b/c I don't think it will affect things, but I'm testing this on help docs that have a row of `=` spanning 78 characters.

Comment: Fascinating explanation.  Thank you!  I suppose in the reverse case then it did matter that I was posting 20 chars while testing on 78 chars.